# How to convert scanned PDF to searchable PDF in Python? [Environment:Windows]

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, text, scanning

I have scanned pdf, I just want to convert searchable PDF by using python. I can convert on Abode but I want to do programmatically and it should be open-source. Can anyone please help to convert the PDF?

Note: It should not remove any image on PDF.

Comment: The question requires a bit clarification. You have a pdf file and you want to do exactly what? Run text recognition?

Comment: No. I just want to convert as searchable PDF, that's it...!

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem by using wand package.
Example code:

```
from pdf2image import convert_from_path

from wand.image import Image as WandImage

TIFFPdf = convert_from_path(pdfFileName)
pageNumber = 0
for img in TIFFPdf:
        pageNumber = pageNumber + 1
   
        img1 = WandImage()
        img1.read(filename='suresh.pdf' + '[' + str(pageNumber) + ']', resolution=300)
        img1.compression = 'group4'
        img1.save(filename=str(pageNumber) + '.tif')
```